# Dynamic LINQ to DataTable: why using hardcode string "it" as DataRow

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic-linq

Assume I have a `DataTable` with three columns `C1`, `C2`, `C3`:

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("C1", typeof (int));
dt.Columns.Add("C2", typeof (string));
dt.Columns.Add("C3", typeof(string));

dt.Rows.Add(1, "1", "1");
dt.Rows.Add(1, "1", "2");
dt.Rows.Add(1, "2", "2");
```

I use [Dynamic Linq on nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic) to `GroupBy` columns `C1` and `C2` like the code below and it works perfectly:

```
 var output = dt.AsEnumerable()
            .AsQueryable()
            .GroupBy("new(it[\"C1\"] as C1, it[\"C2\"] as C2)", "it");
```

If you notice, there is a *hardcode string* `it` to present as `DataRow`, I get this idea from:

[Dynamic Linq GroupBy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469694/dynamic-linq-groupby)

. If I try changing `it` to string `row` for example:

```
GroupBy("new(row[\"C1\"] as C1, row[\"C2\"] as C2)", "row");
```

I will get runtime error:

> > No property or field 'row' exists in type 'DataRow'

So, I don't clear up my mind much why having to *hardcode* `it` as `DataRow`? Is there any reason for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just how the Dynamic LINQ provider is written. It has three hard-coded keywords that it recognizes when it tries to parse the LINQ expressions: `it`, `iff`, and `new`:

```
static readonly string keywordIt = "it";
static readonly string keywordIif = "iif";
static readonly string keywordNew = "new";
```

You can check the [source](https://github.com/kahanu/System.Linq.Dynamic/blob/master/Src/System.Linq.Dynamic/DynamicLinq.cs) to the LINQ assembly yourself if you want to see more details.

(BTW: "it" here appears to be short for "identifier token", if I had to guess.)

Comment: Yes, because your Dynamic LINQ strings are compiled into a Lambda expression, and requires an input parameter. Since there is no way for you to specify what that input parameter is called, they just use the keyword "it" to reference the element of the enumerable. In other words, the `Select("...")` call gets compiled into `Select(it => ...)`

Answer (score 0):

Well I suppose they had to call the current object in the enumeration 'something', so '**it**' seems like a reasonable choice.