# How do I join on an IQueryable? The type is unknown

Tags: casting, entity-framework-6, iqueryable, dynamic-linq

I used dynamic linq to generate search results.  The very last call is .Select("UserID"), which ultimately returns an IQueryable (non-generic interface).

Now, that represents my list of users who meet search criteria.

Next, I'm trying to join those results with the original Users table so I can then join in the rest of the info associated with each user.

When I try to do this:

```
IQueryable<Users> users = /*assume valid instance acquired*/
/*matchingUsers is a valid IQueryable instance returned by a dynamic linq query*/
var results = users
.Join( matchingUsers, u => u.ID, m => m.UserID, (u, m) => u )
```

That fails trying to access m.UserID, because the type of the IQueryable is unknown.  The type is accessible as a Type instance on the IQueryable via the ElementType property, but I don't know how I can use it in this situation.

I've also tried the following:

```
private class UserIDList { public Guid UserID { get; set; } }
filteredUsersDynamicLinqQuery
.Select("new MyNamespace.UserIDList(UserID)")
```

but the new operator can't seem to handle specific type names.  I saw [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8777091/88409) suggesting it could, so maybe the syntax is just wrong, but it may just be a [custom feature](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8785757/88409).

I've tried :

```
var results = users
.Join( matchingUsers.Cast<dynamic>, u => u.ID, m => m.UserID, (u, m) => u )
```

It's highlighted by the compiler with error: "An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation."

I've tried:

```
var results = users
.Join( matchingUsers.Cast<UserIDList>(), u => u.ID, (UserIDList m) => m.UserID, (u, m) => u )
```

But that gives the runtime error: "Additional information: Unable to cast the type 'DynamicClass3' to type 'MyNamespace+UserIDList'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types."  See also: [IQueryable to List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25453212/iqueryable-to-list)

Comment: I actually got this to work by using `matchingUsers.Cast<Guid>` since the IQueryable happened to be returning just a UserID.  But I'm still interested in how to solve this in the general case, where I'm returning more than just a single primitive column.