# Converting object returned from Linq.Dynamic

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, dynamic, dynamic-linq

I am using the [Linq.Dynamic Library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic.3.5/) and EF6. I am attempting to select only the fields from a database that my user selects.

However, all that is returned is a `List<object>`, I have attempted to `Cast<dynamic>`, and every way I can think of, but no matter what the object has 0 fields.

I have also tried explicitly declaring as an `IEnumerable` and that too was unsuccessful, and was unable to call `.ToList()`, without first calling `Cast<T>` which too was unsuccessful.

When converting one of the objects to `string` I get: `"{filenumber=345400, custom2=, custom3=, custom6=4076995332, custom8=4072121417}"`.

The data is being returned I simply cannot cast it to the appropriate type.

```
var query = cmax.dbases
    .Where(w => statuses.Any(a => w.statusname == a) && portfolios.Any(a => w.portfolio == a))
    .Select(string.Format("new ({0})", string.Join(",", fields)))
    .Take(Math.Min((int) takeAmount, count - taken));

var take = await query.ToListAsync();

take.ForEach(data => {
    var type = take.GetType();
    var properties = type.GetProperties();
    var propCount = properties.Count();
    properties.ToList().ForEach(prop => {
        var name = prop.Name;
    });
});
```

Comment: @MUG4N I am using Linq.Dynamic, that does not apply, thanks tho.

Comment: @AdamReed, have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465700/system-linq-dynamic-select-new-into-a-listt-or-any-other-enumerabl

Comment: @EugenePodskal I appreciate your effort!

Comment: @AdamReed That is just strange that they decided to use parentheses instead of curly braces like it is used in C# for anonymous objects. Perhaps it was done exactly to avoid need to escape the braces.

Comment: @Alex Yes, as you can see, I use Reflection here, and am returned with 0 properties. I have no idea what option 2 is. As to option 3, I am using the Library as provided on NuGet and would like to seek an option that doesn't require me expanding on the Library. 

I believe there should be an easy method to `Cast` the object beign returned, that I am overlooking.

Answer (score 1):

In one of my use cases I have converted the results to `List<string[]>` through an extension for IQueryable. As I know my column order in Select("New (columnNames...) "), I could easily figure out which one is which.

so here is the code of the extension

```
public static IList<string[]> ToStringArray(this IQueryable queryFinal)
{
  var query = (IQueryable<dynamic>)queryFinal;
  IList<dynamic> data = query.ToList();
  System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[] props = null;
  if (data.Count > 0) props = data[0].GetType().GetProperties();
  if (props == null) return new List<string[]>();
  /*I do other things using reflection here*/
  return data.Select(d => props.Select(p => (p.GetValue(d, null) ?? string.Empty).ToString()).OfType<string>().ToArray()).ToList();
}
```

use it as

```
var result = query.ToStringArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

The only viable solution I found was to manually parse the data in the string:

```
take.ForEach(data =>
{
    var dbtrData = new DebtorData();
    var cleaned = data.ToString().Replace("{", "").Replace("}", "");
    var pairs = cleaned.Split(',');
    pairs.ToList().ForEach(pair =>
    {
        var key = pair.Split('=')[0].Replace(" ", "");
        var value = pair.Split('=')[1];
        //USEDATA
    }
});
```