# Dynamic Linq Select to a complex object

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic-linq

I had a simple Linq query:

```
var retVal = readModel
    .GroupBy(x => x.Service)
    .Select(
        grp => new GroupView
        {
            GroupName = grp.Key,
            GroupItems = grp.Sum(k => k.NumberOfItems)
        }
    );
```

`retVal` was an `IQueryable<GroupView>`. So far so good, what I'm trying to do is make this query dynamic, so user can use custom grouping strategies.

This is my first attempt:

```
var retVal = readModel
    .GroupBy("Service", "it")
    .Select("it.key");
```

And this give me an array of string containing the name of group. This is fine, but the result that I'm trying to achieve is quite far since I have two unanswerd question:

- How can I translate results to the `GroupView` model
- How can I make that sum?

Comment: What is the type of `GroupName`? a string? would you always group by a property of this type? e.g. string?

Comment: Yes, in this case it is a string, but it could be a Date too, but for now a string it is sufficient.

Comment: Why don't you use your first code but replace `x => x.Service` with a variable of type `Expression<Func<Entity,string>>` where `Entity` is your entity type?

Answer (score 0):

The thing is DynamicLinq doesn't allow it simply.

You can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1468357/1849444) if you want to extend DynamicLinq library to return Strongly Typed results.

But if you don't want it here is a simple solution:

```
//select your grouped results
var retVal = readModel
        .GroupBy("Service", "it")
        .Select("new (it.key as GroupName, Sum(it.NumberOfItems) as GroupItems)");

//Map them
var res = ((IEnumerable<dynamic>)retVal)
          .Select(x => new GroupView 
                 { 
                    GroupName = x.GroupName, 
                    GroupItems = x.GroupItems 
                 });
```