# Select Clause using System.Linq.Dynamic is returning "'(' expected" fault

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, dynamic-linq

I'm trying to use linq dynamic to create a selec that returns me a specific object. But I'm always getting the same error message: '(' expected

My select code:

```
var resultCollection = manyPartEntireCollection
                .Select("new MyNamespace.OneToManyViewModel(@0 as OnePartId, Id as ManyPartId, Name as Name, @1.Contains(outerIt.Id) as Enable)", onePartId, manyParIds)
                .Cast<OneToManyViewModel>()
                .ToList()
                ;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is there any specific reason to use dynamic linq for this small straightforward query?

Comment: "Id" and "Name" are properties that will change according to the entity. It is just an example, but this properties are parametrized. If I use the dynamic way it works fine, but when I try to set a predefined class, as the case of "OneToManyViewModel", occurs this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main question from your example is "what is outerIt?" (*@1.Contains(outerIt.Id)*) This looks to be just a piece of a larger query. You may want to post up the complete set of expressions.

Based on an assumption of what it looks like you are after: It may be possible within a single Linq statement, but often I hit weird-isms around Linq2Entities/Linq2SQL when it comes to view models and native .Net methods/structures so I tend to default to selecting the data separately to the end formatting.

```
var resultCollection = manyPartEntireCollection
  .Select( x => new { ManyPartId = x.Id, x.Name })
  .ToList()
  .Select( x => new OneToManyViewModel 
    {
      OnePartId = onePartId,
      ManyPartId = x.ManyPartId,
      Name = x.Name,
      IsEnabled = manyPartIds.Contains(x.ManyPartId)
    }).ToList();
```

A word of caution about code like this: Initially you may have a reasonable amount of data, but down the road you will encounter potential performance and resource issues with the .ToList() expressions. (No upper limit on # of items.)

update: if DynamicLinq is required, then you can implement the solution offered by dahlbyk on this thread: [System.LINQ.Dynamic: Select(" new (...)") into a List<T> (or any other enumerable collection of <T>)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465700/system-linq-dynamic-select-new-into-a-listt-or-any-other-enumerabl)

the source for System.Linq.Dynamic can be found here: https://github.com/meatGUY/System.Linq.Dynamic  (Updated to meatGUY fork as it looks to be more up to date)

I've created a fork with this implementation available here: https://github.com/StevePy/System.Linq.Dynamic   I'll flick over a pull request to meatGUY to see if it's worth incorporating.

I made the modifications and it appears to do what you would expect. No idea why this hasn't been officially incorporated because it makes quite a bit of sense.  :)

His instructions are easy enough to follow and you will end up with a call that looks like:

```
var resultCollection = manyPartEntireCollection
  .Select<OneToManyViewModel>("new (@0 as OnePartId, Id as ManyPartId, Name as Name, @1.Contains(outerIt.Id) as Enable)", onePartId, manyParIds)
  .ToList();
```

I tested it with a similar object model with the Contains to set a Boolean        flag in the view model and it worked a treat. Caveat though is on what that "outerIt" reference goes to.

Comment: when I try to make by the dynamic mode, it works fine. But when I try to set a type, as "OneToManyViewModel" class, the error occurs. It looks like the error is in the "new MyNamespace.OneToManyViewModel (". Also, as I replied above to Kishna, I need the code to be dynamic and return the this specified type. Thx –

Comment: I think I found the solution to what you're looking for, I've updated my answer with the details and links to how to implement a generic return type on Dynamic Linq Select.