# Query to get only root/base entities in EF Code first

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

Assume:

```
BaseEntity
ChildEntity : BaseEntity
```

The problem is getting the base entities with an efficient way. What I know that works is this type of query:

```
var results = context.BaseEntities.Where(entity => !(entity is ChildEntity) );
```

However this is **very** prone to breaking, as simply adding another extension to `BaseEntity`, like `ChildEntityTwo : BaseEntity` will break the query (query will include `BaseEntity` and `ChildEntityTwo` types.

Also, I havent had the chance to profile it yet but I suspect the query downloads **all** the entities and filters them in memory, but I could be wrong with this one.

Note that the solution `context.BaseEntities.OfType<BaseEntities>()` will actually include and download all the entities as well! It only works when you need an endpoint class, like `ChildEntityTwo`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retrieve only base class from Entity Framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056092/retrieve-only-base-class-from-entity-framework)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ESQL offers [`OFTYPE ONLY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399295.aspx) operator for this purpose but that operator doesn't have any equivalent in Linq. You can use [this workaround](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/09/17/tip-35-how-to-write-oftypeonly-tentity.aspx) to build `OFTYPE ONLY` for Linq.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Went with the workaround, plus this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11252096/how-to-convert-dbset-in-entity-framework-to-objectquery that helps access the objectcontext, but it uses magic strings. Any idea how I could make that without magic strings?

Comment: Moreover, any way to use this extension on an ICollection navigation property? I am studying this as we speak too.

Comment: Also snooping around I found this 'http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.commandtrees.expressionbuilder.dbexpressionbuilder.oftypeonly%28v=vs.110%29.aspx' but i have absolutely no clue as to how I can access the CommandTree

Comment: As it seems that's thats a substrate and not available easily other than ESQL