# Dynamic select query in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, join

I am in need to join two data tables and retrieve some columns(which will chosen dynamically) from the joined table. I have used the LINQ query to perform joins but i was not able to select columns columns dynamically.

The code is:

```
    var q = (from pd in tableOne.AsEnumerable()
                 join od in tableTwo.AsEnumerable() on pd.Field<string>(leftTableColumn) equals od.Field<string>(rightTableColumn)
                 select new
                 {
                     Column1=pd.Field<dynamic>(reuiredColumn1),
                     Column2=od.Field<dynamic>(requireColumn2)

                 });
```

here tableOne and tableTwo are Data Tables. The problem here is I can always able to get only two columns(column1,column2) as per the query.But i am in need to form the select query dynamically based on the user selection.

Can anyone please share any idea regards how to achieve this result?

Comment: Your question isn't much clear

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve? A data grid with variable user defined columns? Is this `Entity Framework` or `Linq-to-SQL`?

**Easy version**

- If there is not hundreds of columns, I'd just load all the columns and hide only the columns i want to show in the GUI.

**Hard version**

- If you really need to load only a few columns from the DB. I'd recommend using the Extension methods version of `LINQ` (i.e. `tableOne.Select(lambda expression)` ) and create the [Anonymous type as an expression dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740532/how-to-use-expression-to-build-an-anonymous-type).

Comment: OP is using `DataTable`s and [DataTableExtensions.AsEnumerable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks didn't get that, I will delete the part about the AsEnumerable method then.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly. You can once select your main tables and then based on some conditions select the columns that you want. Here is the untested code

```
 var q = (from pd in tableOne
                 join od in tableTwo on pd.Field equals od.Field
                 select new
                 {
                     pd, 
                     od
                 });

if(somecondition)
{
   var q1 = from result in q
        select q.pd.yourcoloumns;
} 
else 
{
    var q1 = from result in q
            select q.od.yourcoloumns;
}
```

In my example the `pd` and `od` are your tables.

Comment: Regards the following (var q1 = from result in q
        select q.pd.yourcoloumns;) in your code how to select multiple columns in a same query? I am using like this,  var q1 = from result in q
                         select q.Select(i=>i.pd[reuiredColumn1]);...still i able to get only one column at a time.

Comment: with comman seperated `q.Select(i=>i.pd.Coloumns1, i.pd.coloumn2)` put a dot `.` after `pd` or `od`