# How to create Composite Key expression dynamically?

Tags: c#, lambda

I need to crate Composite Key dynamically with anonymous type like follow.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<TEntity>().HasKey(**x => new { x.Property1, x.Property2}**);
```

I managed to crate dynamically for single key. But I've no idea how to crate for composite key. I've spent enough time on google for this solution, but I couldn't find one.
Any help would appreciate.

Comment: Related: [How to create LINQ Expression Tree with anonymous type in it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/606104/how-to-create-linq-expression-tree-with-anonymous-type-in-it)

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<TEntity>().HasKey(x => x.Property1).HasKey(x => x.Property2);
```