# How to deserialize using JSON.Net to an anonymous type?

Tags: c#, json.net

Just trying to create an anonymous type from JSON without knowing anything about the parameters ahead of time, and fully interpreting them (possibly with hints).  i.e. that value "looks" like an int, string, or date.

The only way that I know of so far is to create an anonymous type that you have pre-knowledge of.  See the .DeserializeAnonymousType(...) method below.

Can anyone do better than this?  Thanks.

```
        var jsonString = "{\"user_id\": 1, \"user_type\": \"moderator\", \"name\": \"Fred\"}";

        JToken root = JObject.Parse(jsonString);

        var anonTemplate = new{user_id=0, user_type="", name="" };

        var a = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(root.ToString(), anonTemplate);


        var b = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Object>(root.ToString());  // actually turns into a JsonObject which is something differet.
```

---

**Update**

I downloaded dynamicduck and am playing with it a little.  Will this weird dynamic "wrapper" idea of Brian's be -able in the ways I need (serializable, etc)?

http://weblogs.asp.net/britchie/archive/2010/08/05/json-net-dynamic-extensions.aspx

http://weblogs.asp.net/britchie/archive/2010/08/03/dynamicduck-duck-typing-in-a-dynamic-world.aspx

Comment: In case of .NET 4 I assume that you should be able deserialize to `dynamic` object and then explicitly access required properties

Comment: How do you intend to consume this object if you do not know what parameters it has or is expected to have?

Comment: @sll: got an example?  Not against dynamic types.  I'm using them on occasion.  In that case, my next question would be how do you convert from dynamic to an anon type.  I'm happy with either path because performance is not an issue, however, I *do* need an anon type in this case (existing libraries).

Comment: @KallDrexx: there's other dynamic DSL stuff going on.

Comment: <a href="http://www.drowningintechnicaldebt.com/ShawnWeisfeld/archive/2010/08/22/using-c-4.0-and-dynamic-to-parse-json.aspx">This article</a> outlines how to return a C# dynamic, although not with Json.net

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can deserialize with JSON.NET to an [`ExpandoObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx) using the [`ExpandoObjectConverter`](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Converters_ExpandoObjectConverter.htm).

To create an anonymous type at runtime, its quite a bit more complicated, take a look at the hoops jumped through in this thread:

[How to create LINQ Expression Tree to select an anonymous type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606104/how-to-create-linq-expression-tree-with-anonymous-type-in-it)

As you can see quite a bit of effort that probably is not worth it as you still wouldn't get any compile time safety.  So a [dynamic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd264741.aspx) or ExpandoObject are your best bets.

Comment: do you have a example of ExpandoObjectConverter usage that you could link to?