# Converting a JObject to an Anonymous type

Tags: c#, json, linq, elasticsearch

I have a JObject and want to format that JObject to an Object. My JSON stirng is

```
{"Prop1":"Prop1Value","Prop2":1,"Prop3":"Prop3Value","dtProp":"2019-12-30T09:59:48"}
```

I want this JSON string to be formatted as

```
{
    Prop1 = "Prop1Value",
    Prop2 = 1,
    Prop3 = "Prop3Value",
    dtProp = "2019-12-30T09:59:48"
}
```

How can we do this? My JSON string is not a strongly typed Object. But I want to convert that into this format. My Json string will not be of same at every time. It changes each time. Can I create an object dynamically for this scenario?

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Could you use `ExpandoObject` as shown in [How to deserialize using JSON.Net to an anonymous type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7995856/3744182)?   If not, truly creating an anonymous type object in runtime is very difficult, see [How to create LINQ Expression Tree to select an anonymous type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/606104/3744182).

Comment: Or are you looking for [Custom JSON Derivative Format](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30610196/3744182)?  That question shows how to replace the `:` separator between JSON object keys and values with `=`.

Comment: I would go for QuoteName Property or something simple like that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7553516/json-net-serialize-property-name-without-quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please do note that JSONs are not formatted with `=`, instead with a `:`. You wont be able to deserialize it once its formatted with `=`.

You can do this,

```
  string newFormatted = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(JObject.Parse(json), Formatting.Indented).Replace(":", "=");
  Console.WriteLine(newFormatted);
```

**Output**

```
{
  "Prop1"= "Prop1Value",
  "Prop2"= 1,
  "Prop3"= "Prop3Value",
  "dtProp"= "2019-12-30T09=59=48"
}
```

**Printing Without Quotes on Keys**

If you are interested in printing the Keys without quotes, you can run the following method. This method breaks each line and removes quotes from Each Key.

```
    string str = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(JObject.Parse(json), Formatting.Indented);
    string newStr = string.Empty;
    str.Split(Environment.NewLine).ToList().ForEach(line => newStr += string.Join("=", line.Split(':').Select((x, index) => index % 2 == 0 ? x.Replace(@"""", "") : x)) + Environment.NewLine);
```

**Output**

```
{
  Prop1= "Prop1Value"
  Prop2= 1
  Prop3= "Prop3Value"
  dtProp= "2019-12-30T09=59=48"
}
```

Comment: Where are the quotes that the OP wants around the values?

Comment: Yes, I don't want the quotes in the output.