# Databinding to runtime types

Tags: wpf, data-binding, dynamic, linq-to-entities, expression

I am using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606104/how-to-create-linq-expression-tree-with-anonymous-type-in-it) to define dynamic query `IQueryable`  and set the result as `itemssource` of wpf datagrid.
I get this error in output window:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'DynamicProp1' property not found on 'object' ''DynamicType1' ....
```

when I try it with `dynamic` keyword I get success.

```
dynamic d = item;
var v = d.DynamicProp1;//works
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On `dynamic` you always set [properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx), the code in that other question seemed to define [fields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118.aspx), which cannot be bound.

(Use [`TypeBuilder.DefineProperty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.typebuilder.defineproperty.aspx) instead of `DefineField`)