# Converting List<string> to EntityFramework column/field list

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Using EntityFramework, I can get a list of entities of a certain type using the following syntax:

```
List<Customer> customers = ((IQueryable<Customer>)myEntities.Customers
     .Where(c => c.Surname == strSurname)
     .OrderBy(c => c.Surname)).ToList<Customer>();
```

I can then do something like this to end up with only the data I'm interested in:

```
var customerSummaries = from s in customers
     select new
     {
        s.Surname, s.FirstName, s.Address.Postcode
     };
```

I'm given a list of `string`s (based on user selection) of the fields (and tables where necessary) that comprise the requested summarized data.  Eg for the above 'customerSummary' the list of `string`s provided would be:  "Surname", "FirstName", "Address.Postcode".

My question is: How do I convert that list of strings into the syntax needed to extract only the specified fields?

If that can't be done, what would be a better type (than string) for the list of columns so I can extract the right info?

I guess I need to know the type that an EF [entity|table]'s [member|column|field] is, if that makes sense.

EDIT:

I tried the suggested answer - dynamic linq - using the following syntax

```
string parmList = "Surname, Firstname, Address.Postcode";
var customers = myEntities.Customers.Select(parmList)
  .OrderBy("Address.Postcode");
```

but this results in: `EntitySqlException was unhandled.  'Surname' could not be resolved in the current scope or context. Make sure that all referenced variables are in scope, that required schemas are loaded, and that namespaces are referenced correctly.`

So, a follow-up question.  Am I using `Select` properly?  I have only seen examples using the `Where` and `OrderBy` clauses, but I think I'm doing it right based on those.

If my Select syntax is not the problem, can anyone see what is?

Edit 2: It was upside down.  This works:

```
string parmList = "Surname, Firstname, Address.Postcode";
var customers = myEntities.Customers
  .OrderBy("Address.Postcode")
  .Select(parmList);
```

Comment: Is there an alternate approach you can use?  For example a stored proc?  It may not be linq but it would be pretty simple to implement if its a one off thing.

Comment: I've thought of using straight sql and if/when I'm beaten I'll give that a try, but not just yet.  :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use *dynamic linq*, check it in [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx). It is also available on [nuget](http://nuget.org/packages/DynamicLINQ/)

Comment: Thanks for the links, could you possibly have a look at my edit?

Answer (score 2):

> I suggest `dynamic linq` as @Cuong already posted.

But for simple `Select` projections and as a hand-made exercise in expressions...

**Using `LinqRuntimeTypeBuilder`** from [How to create LINQ Expression Tree to select an anonymous type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606104/how-to-create-linq-expression-tree-with-anonymous-type-in-it)
(see the comments there for 'why' is that necessary)

And **add this**...

```
public static IQueryable SelectDynamic(this IQueryable source, IEnumerable<string> fieldNames)
{
    Dictionary<string, PropertyInfo[]> sourceProperties = new Dictionary<string, PropertyInfo[]>();
    foreach (var propertyPath in fieldNames)
    {
        var props = propertyPath.Split('.');
        var name = props.Last();
        PropertyInfo[] infos;
        if (sourceProperties.TryGetValue(name, out infos))
            name = string.Join("", props);
        sourceProperties[name] = source.ElementType.GetDeepProperty(props);
    }

    Type dynamicType = LinqRuntimeTypeBuilder.GetDynamicType(sourceProperties.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value.Last().PropertyType));

    ParameterExpression sourceItem = Expression.Parameter(source.ElementType, "t");
    IEnumerable<MemberBinding> bindings = dynamicType.GetFields()
        .Select(p => Expression.Bind(p, sourceItem.MakePropertyExpression(sourceProperties[p.Name]))).OfType<MemberBinding>();

    Expression selector = Expression.Lambda(Expression.MemberInit(
        Expression.New(dynamicType.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes)), bindings), sourceItem);

    MethodCallExpression selectExpression = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), "Select", new Type[] { source.ElementType, dynamicType }, Expression.Constant(source), selector);
    return Expression.Lambda(selectExpression).Compile().DynamicInvoke() as IQueryable;
}

public static PropertyInfo[] GetDeepProperty(this Type type, params string[] props)
{
    List<PropertyInfo> list = new List<PropertyInfo>();
    foreach (var propertyName in props)
    {
        var info = type.GetProperty(propertyName);
        type = info.PropertyType;
        list.Add(info);
    }
    return list.ToArray();
}

public static Expression MakePropertyExpression(this ParameterExpression sourceItem, PropertyInfo[] properties)
{
    Expression property = sourceItem;
    foreach (var propertyInfo in properties)
        property = Expression.Property(property, propertyInfo);
    return property;
}
```

**Use it like** e.g.:

```
public static IEnumerable<object> 
    SelectAsEnumerable(this IQueryable entitySet, params string[] propertyPath)
{
    return entitySet.SelectDynamic(propertyPath) as IEnumerable<object>;
}
var list = db.YourEntity.SelectAsEnumerable("Name", "ID", "TestProperty.ID").ToList();
```

**Note:**
You can use similar approach to expand for OrderBy etc. - but this wasn't meant to cover all angles (or any real queries)

`Deep Property Expressions` from [this post of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15975319/417747)

---