# How to create lambda expression that returns object's property, having this property's name?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

I am completely lost on this one. I have a piece of code that does what I need when implemented like this:

```
return filters.Add(m => m.Metadata.RecordId).IsEqualTo(1);
```

where m is a `TestObj` class object and `Add` method's argument is `Expression<Func<TestObj,bool?>>`.

Now the problem is that I cannot hardcode m.Metadata.RecordId inside Add, because what I get here is a string that informs me about the property that should be used, in this case "Metadata.RecordId". what I need to do is to construct such an expression with this string that will do the same thing as m => m.Metadata.RecordId does. I need something like this:

```
string propertyName = "Metadata.RecordId";
Expression expr = null;//create expression here somehow that will do the same as m => m.Metadata.RecordId
return filters.Add(expr).IsEqualTo(1);
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what exactly you want there as an output (bool, int and comparing),
But this should get you on the right track...

```
public static void Test(string propertyPath)
{
    var props = propertyPath.Split('.');
    Expression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TestObj), "x");
    Expression property = parameter;
    foreach (var propertyName in props)
        property = Expression.Property(property, propertyName);
    Expression<Func<TestObj, int>> lambdaExpression =
        Expression.Lambda<Func<TestObj, int>>(property, parameter as ParameterExpression);
    Add(lambdaExpression);
}
static void Add(Expression<Func<TestObj, int>> paramExp)
{
    TestObj obj = new TestObj { Metadata = new Metadata { RecordId = 1, Name = "test" } };
    var id = paramExp.Compile()(obj);
}
```

And you can also check this post of Jon's which nicely describes how that works...
[Use reflection to get lambda expression from property Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7246715/use-reflection-to-get-lambda-expression-from-property-name/7246796#7246796)

Answer (score 0):

What about this call:

```
return filters.Add(m => ReflectionMagic(m, "Metadata.RecordId").IsEqualTo(1);
```

The method would have this signature:

```
public object ReflectionMagic(object source, string property);
```

If that would work, you could do something like this:

```
var propertyTree = property.Split('.');

foreach(var propertyName in propertyTree)
{
     var propInfo = source.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
     var source = propInfo.GetValue(source, null);
}

return source;
```

Be aware that any kind of argument and return value checks are missing and are left as an excercise to the reader.

Comment: doesn't work - i've tried. it's not a lambda expression - it's a static property return

Comment: What I don't understand the Add method should take an expression a func takes tastobj and return bool, as I see from Question. Please enlighten me.+1