# Adding Expression argument as property in LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-6, expression-trees

Using EF6, how would I bind a given `Expression<Func<Row, string>>` argument to an existing select expression, without having to rewrite every property binding using expression trees?

```
public IEnumerable<RowModel> GetRowModels(Expression<Func<Row, string>> textExpr)
{
    return from row in MyDatabaseContext.MyTable
           select new RowModel
           {
               RowID = row.ID,
               CreatedDate = row.CreatedDate,
               AnotherProperty = row.AnotherProperty,
               Text = textExpr, // how do I bind this expression?
               Value = row.OtherStuff.Where(os => os.ShouldUse).Select(os => os.Value).FirstOrDefault(),
               AnotherValue = row.OtherStuff.Where(os => os.ShouldUseAgain).Select(os => os.Value).FirstOrDefault()
           };
}
```

Comment: What is `OtherStuff` in your example.  It is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: @BenRobinson How is `OtherStuff` relevant to this question?  Clearly that line is already working.

Comment: `OtherStuff` is just there to show why I'm trying to avoid building all property bindings with expression trees.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need here is a method to combine several expressions.  Specifically, what we would like is a way to take an expression that maps a value and then also accept an expression that accepts the input of the first expression, and the output of the first expression, and computes a new value.

As an implementation of this method we can replace all instances of "the result of the first function" with the body of the first function; after that all that needs to be done is to ensure that both expressions are using the same `Parameter` instance.

```
public static Expression<Func<TFirstParam, TResult>>
    Combine<TFirstParam, TIntermediate, TResult>(
    this Expression<Func<TFirstParam, TIntermediate>> first,
    Expression<Func<TFirstParam, TIntermediate, TResult>> second)
{
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TFirstParam), "param");

    var newFirst = first.Body.Replace(first.Parameters[0], param);
    var newSecond = second.Body.Replace(second.Parameters[0], param)
        .Replace(second.Parameters[1], newFirst);

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TFirstParam, TResult>>(newSecond, param);
}
```

The following code is used to replace all instances of an expression with another:

```
public static Expression Replace(this Expression expression,
    Expression searchEx, Expression replaceEx)
{
    return new ReplaceVisitor(searchEx, replaceEx).Visit(expression);
}
internal class ReplaceVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly Expression from, to;
    public ReplaceVisitor(Expression from, Expression to)
    {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
    }
    public override Expression Visit(Expression node)
    {
        return node == from ? to : base.Visit(node);
    }
}
```

As for using the function; it's simple enough.  We call `Combine` on your `textExpression`, and then we can create a lambda accepting both the row and the text result of the first expression as parameters.  This lets you write a lambda that's almost exactly like the one you already have, but where you can use the text parameter to assign the `Text` value:

```
public IEnumerable<RowModel> GetRowModels(
    Expression<Func<Row, string>> textExpr)
{
    return MyDatabaseContext.MyTable.Select(
        textExpr.Combine((row, text) => new RowModel
    {
        RowID = row.ID,
        CreatedDate = row.CreatedDate,
        AnotherProperty = row.AnotherProperty,
        Text = text, // how do I bind this expression?
        Value = row.OtherStuff.Where(os => os.ShouldUse)
            .Select(os => os.Value).FirstOrDefault(),
        AnotherValue = row.OtherStuff.Where(os => os.ShouldUseAgain)
            .Select(os => os.Value).FirstOrDefault()
    }));
}
```