# LINQ to Entities : "select new" expression tree throws System.NotSupportedException

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, expression-trees

I'm trying to build an Expression Tree that reflects a "select new" query.

I'm using Ethan's answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606104/how-to-create-linq-expression-tree-with-anonymous-type-in-it).
It works great for common lists but with LINQ to Entities I get this exception:

```
System.NotSupportedException: Unable to create a constant value of type X.
Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.
```

Where X is the Entity I'm querying.

Using the debugger this is the IQueryable with the expression tree:

```
SELECT [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id],
       [Extent1].[Nombre] AS [Nombre],
       [Extent1].[Apellido] AS [Apellido]
FROM [dbo].[Empleadoes] AS [Extent1]
```

```
.Select(t => new Nombre;String;() {Nombre = t.Nombre})
```

And this is the IQueryable using normal linq notation (not actually the same query but to get the point - they are different)

```
SELECT [Extent1].[Dni] AS [Dni],
       [Extent1].[Nombre] + N' ' + [Extent1].[Apellido] AS [C1]
FROM [dbo].[Empleadoes] AS [Extent1]
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking through [Dynamic LINQ](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) code I found the problem.

Ethan's solution does this:

```
source.Provider.CreateQuery(
    Expression.Call(
        typeof(Queryable),
        "Select",
        new Type[] { source.ElementType, dynamicType },
        Expression.Constant(source),
        selector));
```

And inside Dynamic.cs of Dynamic LINQ they do this:

```
source.Provider.CreateQuery(
    Expression.Call(
        typeof(Queryable),
        "Select",
        new Type[] { source.ElementType, lambda.Body.Type },
        source.Expression,
        Expression.Quote(lambda)));
```

The relevant change is in the 4th parameter of the call to Expression.Call.