# dynamically build select clause linq

Tags: c#, linq, select, dynamic, expression

```
class someClass
{ 
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    ...
    public string someProperty { get; set; }          
}

Expression<Func<someClass, object>> selector = null;
selector = k => new { k.Id ,k.Name };
var serult = myData.Select(selector);

// .Select(p=> new {p.Name , p.Id}) etc.
```

This sample code is working 
But;

```
Expression<Func<someClass, ???>> createSelector(string[] fields)
{
    ...
    ....
    return ...
} 

Expression<Func<someClass, ???>> selector = createSelector({"Name","Id"});
```

Is this possible?
This method when running create dynamic selector

Comment: Yes, this is possible.  You need to use reflection to build an expression tree dynamically.  Here's an example of building an expression tree dynamically http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882637.aspx

Comment: I think you should take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/606104/how-to-create-linq-expression-tree-with-anonymous-type-in-it

Answer (score 1):

This can be used to create the expression you need.

```
    public static Expression<Func<T, TReturn>> CreateSelector<T, TReturn>(string fieldName)
        where T : class
        where TReturn : class
    {
        ParameterExpression p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "t");
        Expression body = Expression.Property(p, fieldName);
        Expression conversion = Expression.Convert(body, typeof(object));
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, TReturn>>(conversion, new ParameterExpression[] { p });
    }
```

Comment: I dont know return type (can be anonymous type) and the fildName can be multiply
the best result
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16516971/linq-dynamic-select
but return type must be object or anonymous type 
this example not work

Comment: @AhmetGünaydın The return type would be the list you are querying. Could you loop through the multiple parameters adding a new select to an IQueryable object?