# Group by multiple columns using expression trees

Tags: linq, dynamic, group-by, multiple-columns

I have the following query which does not work

```
var municipalities = session.Query<Repositorio_Resultado>()
                .Where(x => ...)
                .GroupBy(GetExpression(argument))
                .Select(x => new SelGeo_DTO()
                 { 
                     COORD_LAT = x.Average(y => y.CoordYLat.Value),
                     COORD_LON = x.Average(y => y.CoordXLon.Value)
                })
                .ToList();
```

where GetExpression is this

```
private Expression<Func<Repositorio_Resultado, object>> GetExpression(string level2GroupBy)
    {
        ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Repositorio_Resultado), "x");

        Type anonymousType = new { Key1 = "", Key2 = "" }.GetType();
        NewExpression ne = Expression.New(anonymousType);
        MemberInitExpression mie = Expression.MemberInit(ne, new MemberBinding[]
        {
            Expression.Bind(anonymousType.GetMember("Key1")[0], Expression.Constant(level2GroupBy)),
            Expression.Bind(anonymousType.GetMember("Key2")[0], Expression.Constant(string.Format("ID_{0}", level2GroupBy)))
        });

        return Expression.Lambda<Func<Repositorio_Resultado, object>>(mie, pe);
    }
```

what I want to do is implement

```
.GroupBy(x => new { x.A, x.B })
```

and then in the Select that follows I want to use x.Key.Key1, x.Key.Key2. Currently the error I get is

```
Type '<>f__AnonymousType2`2[System.String,System.String]' does not have a default constructor
```

on the NewExpression ne = Expression.New(anonymousType); line. I am not sure on the return type of the GetExpression method too, it's probably wrong.

Comment: try see about [memberinitexpression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.memberinitexpression(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create LINQ Expression Tree to select an anonymous type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/606104/how-to-create-linq-expression-tree-to-select-an-anonymous-type)

Comment: I would like to use the dynamic linq library, using strings. Do you know how to write that select clause in that way?

Comment: if you use DynamicLinq so it should be something like this `.GroupBy("new(it.A, it.B)")`

Comment: when you say _dynamic linq library_ you mean this https://dynamiclinq.codeplex.com/ or something else?

Comment: if so, you can use `var tt = t.GroupBy("new (it.num, it.num2)", "it");`

Comment: I abandoned dynamic linq and now am back in trying to solve my problem with expression trees, can you help Grundy?

Comment: if you want epression trees, see link above - you can see complex sample for creating and using anonymous type with expresion tree