# Custom string in linq to entity select new

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq, model-view-controller

Is there any way to customize it?

This is what Im trying to do:

```
string customSelect = "c.person_name";
int per = PersonID();
var RetrievItem = (from c in db.person where c.person_id == per select new { customSelect }).FirstOrDefault();
```

I've tried to debugging it but it just ended up retrieving given string instead of value from database

Any suggestions @_ @?

Comment: why not `select new { c.person_name}` ?

Comment: Look at the [Expression class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Mostafiz cause that string is coming dynamically and is gonna be different every time @_ @

Comment: Have you tried c.customSelect?

Comment: @gayan1991 yeah, it says that my db model does not contains definition of fk

Comment: Have a look at to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/723018/1380428).

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Hamlet's comment about an expression based solution, you can have a look at the [Dynamic Linq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic/) library. It supports lamba expressions defined as strings, which is exactly what you need.

Comment: I would rather say this is the only possible dynamic select solution so far because you cannot create anonymous types at runtime, which Dynamic LINQ solves by creating dynamic classes at runtime. +1

Comment: @IvanStoev, no it is possible to create dynamic type at runtime

Comment: @AdilMammadov It's possible, but hard. And not **anonymous** type which is compiler feature.

Comment: @IvanStoev, I agree with that it is hard, especially, when you add *properties* instead of *fields* ([link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2sd82fz7(v=vs.110).aspx)) :).

Comment: @AdilMammadov Yeah :) Dynamic LINQ has a handy `DynamicExpression.CreateClass()` method which does all that, and also implements correctly `Equals` and `GetHashCode` plus the caching.