# Dynamically generate lambda expression

Tags: c#, .net-core, lambda

I have the following class:

```
public class Movie
{
    public int MovieId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

I want to create a lambda expression like this, which contained all properties of the class:

```
m => new { m.MovieId, m.Title }
```

Is it possible to generate that dynamically? Thanks

Comment: I suspect you're trying to do something similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606104/how-to-create-linq-expression-tree-to-select-an-anonymous-type

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? Why do you need to generate an anonymous type by copying the properties of a concrete type? I suspect you're trying to solve a problem in the wrong way.